# Send query param in GET request only if the optional field is entered by the user in form

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a form that has below 2 values userId (required) , userType(optional). Is there a better way to handle the optional field value in url so that its added to url only if provided by user else the url strips out the userType and sends only the required filed i.e. userId.
I know i can use a ternary but is there a better way

```
const getReportData = async () => {
 const externalUrl = `/users/report/${formProps.values.userId.value}?userType=${formProps.values.userType.value}`
return API.get({url: externalUrl,});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const getReportData = async () => {
const { userId, userType } = formProps.values;

let url = `/users/report/${userId.value}`;

if (userType.value) {
  url += `?userType=${userType.value}`;
}

return API.get({ url });
};
```

Comment: `form.props` should be `formProps.values`.

Comment: yep thats correct Arun, and instead of let .. i could use a const like ```const urlParams = userType?.value ? `?userType=${userType.value}`: null;```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my template string and it worked

```
const externalUrl = `/users/report/${formProps.values.userId.value}${formProps.values.userType?.value?`userType=${formProps.values.userType.value}`:``}`
```

but doesnt look that readable.

Comment: The URL is missing `?userType=`.

Comment: Updated the code above to a shorter solution. Check it out

Answer (score -1):

You can use this for more code readability:

```
const getReportData = async () => {
   const { userId, userType } = formProps.values;

   const url = `/users/report/${userId.value}`;

   if (!userType || !userType.value)
      return API.get({ url });

   return API.get({ url: `${url}?userType=${userType.value}` });
};
```